# An HTTP POST request shows an HTML error instead of showing a the request body

Tags: post, coffeescript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using `casperjs` to post to an URL and using `fiddler2` to debug my code. Below is my code (written in `coffeescript`).

```
casper = require('casper').create({
    waitTimeout    : 10000,
    verbose        : true,
    logLevel       : 'debug',
    userAgent      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
    ignoreSslErrors: true,
    viewportSize   : {
        width : 1080,
        height: 1024
    }

})

url = "http://www.sample.com/test"
casper.start()
casper.thenOpen(url, {
        method: "post",
        data  : {
            a     : "aaa",
            b     : "bbb",
            c     : "ccc"
        },
        headers: {
            "User-Agent"  : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36777",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "text/plain, */*"
        }
    },
    ->
        console.log this.getPageContent()
)

casper.run()
```

When I run it, I got below debug info:

```
C:\casperjs\batchbin\cj.bat C:\Users\***\WebstormProjects\haha\test.coffee
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://www.sample.com/test, HTTP POST
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.sample.com/test, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://www.sample.com/test"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 http://www.sample.com/test (HTTP 200)
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 1: Start tag expected.</div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror></body></html>
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 657ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 675ms

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, from fiddler, my post request is:

```
POST http://www.sample.com/test HTTP/1.1
Origin: null
Content-Length: ***
Accept: text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36777
Cookie: ***
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US,*
Host: www.sample.com

a=aaa&b=bbb&c=ccc
```

And my post response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 14:36:34 GMT
Content-Length: ***

http://www.sample.com/this_is_a_sample_url
```

Note that the response body in an URL **http://www.sample.com/this_is_a_sample_url**. But the `getPageContent()` gives me a piece of html code. At first I think the problem may caused by the `Accept` request header. However, it's already been set to `text/plain` and not HTML. 
Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server's response may contain the correct data, but since it returns a URL as XML, PhantomJS cannot parse this correctly. This is why there is an error shown as an HTML page.

You should specifically use [`__utils__.sendAJAX`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax) to download the content (in JavaScript):

```
casper.post = function(url, data){
    return this.evaluate(function(targetURL){
        return __utils__.sendAJAX(targetURL, "POST", data, false, {
            overrideMimeType: "text/plain"
        });
    }, url);
};

casper.start("http://example.com").then(function(){
    var content = this.post(targetURL, {
        a     : "aaa",
        b     : "bbb",
        c     : "ccc"
    });
    // do something with content
}).run();
```

At the beginning a dummy (existing) page is opened to initialize the system properly. You also need to run CasperJS with the [`--web-security=false`](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) command line option, when the dummy domain differs from your actual request domain.

If you use a dummy local html file on `start`, you should add the [`--local-to-remote-url-access=true`](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) command line option, because the current URL is about:blank and AJAX requests are restricted to the current domain.

Comment: Hi Artjom, where should I put this piece of code? I put it in the top level and got "CasperError: No steps defined, aborting". Also is there a way to specify the custom HTTP request headers? I only need to post to a URL and no other steps, so I don't think I can `start` on this URL.

Comment: Inside of a `then` block, I also forgot the necessary command line option. See my updated answer.

Comment: I use the code just as you provided and `console.log(content)` when I got the return values. I can not see the request from fiddler. Did I miss something? What I got are: [info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 1 step
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
null
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 1/1: done in 28ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 1 steps in 44ms

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Just tried it out. It should have worked. I found a workaround.

Comment: I found the problem. It's because the target_url can't be accessed from within the `evaluate` block. To make it can be accessed from within `evaluate`, we need to pass the target_url as an additional parameter to `evaluate` and add a parameter to the anonymous function to capture the value.

Comment: Thank you very much Artjom B! You are a casperjs&phantomjs ninja!

Comment: Thank you! I meant `targetURL` as a placeholder and not as an actual variable, I will clarify.

Comment: I've also change it a little so that it is now reusable.